# Video games are called video games and not computer games?

Tags: etymology

We all know what video games stand for. However I'm not too sure if the word video game is the right word for it. Why not just say computer game?

A video game , would be in my opinion if a movie director tries to cut certain parts of a video to his amusement.

A video is something that is recorded on a medium (digital or analog). A 'video game' is interactive in its nature.

Comment: Some computer games were text-only, and could be played on an interactive teletype with no video display. Believe me, I've played some, back in the '70s, over acoustic modems. Computer games with video components are a subset (even if they are the vast majority today) of computer games overall.

Comment: I've played games on regular cassette tapes , and I was shocked when I first played them as it was in 1995 when an older friend of mine pulled this old tape console out of nowhere. If games were text only, were they called video games back then?

Comment: If games were text only they were not called video games.

Comment: Back in the day, I often used to play [Space Invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders) (always in the *pub*, not once in an "amusement arcade"). It would never have occurred to anyone to call that a ***computer** game* (computers were virtually unknown to the general public). It was a ***video** game*.

Comment: I've actually closevoted as POB, but on reflection I think this is just a pedantic ***peeve***.

Comment: There were video games long before there were computer games.  (At least in dog years.)  [**Pong**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong) was the first popular video game, and it was released in 1972.  The Apple II and other early personal computers and weren't released until 1977.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: "Video" refers to devices which manipulate and present visual images.  A "video camera", eg, may simply be a camera which sends the image to a television screen, without recording it anywhere.

Comment: I think this must be opinion based - in my area, nobody calls them video games. They are called computer games, or just games (especially by younger generations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have attached a concept to a word that was perhaps never there. Etymologically speaking, [video is the visual equivalent of audio](http://www.etymonline.com/), and as such I think the best analogy you could make is to compare a video tape to an audio tape. An audio tape is a record of sound, whereas a video tape stores record of colored light. Thus a video game would be a game you play with the visuals emitted from something, like oh say a television.

However, do not think I am posting this answer just to quell your counfoundment. A computer game? Pshaw, computers are not anywhere as new as you think, ya whippersnapper! [We had them since the 17th century!](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=computer) A computer game should be something some sort of math teacher designed to teach kids how to multiply and subtract on an abacus or something of the sort.

As for common use, although both the video game and the computer game are both technically played on a computer, the type of computer that played a video game was very especially built for the sole purpose of playing them, so you would not normally consider it a computer, as computers were multi-functional business devices, with game playing capabilities as a peripheral feature. The distinction between devices gets more and more blurred everyday, as video game systems get more features and computers get less (e.g. smartphones), and the word video gets used less now that [dvds have displaced video tapes.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=video+tape%2Cdvd&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvideo%20tape%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdvd%3B%2Cc0) Well, that's not entirely true actually. Youtube videos are still very popular, and they're still videos despite the fact that they have nothing to do with the video tape medium which familiarized many of us with the word.

Perhaps things would have gone more along the lines of what you are thinking if Nintendo had released the Family Computer in its original form in the U.S.A., as it was  the name of the Nintendo which was synonymous for video games of every sort up until *at least* Sega proved themselves to be a valid competitor, if not somewhere within the Playstation era. However when the [N.E.S. came out in they were trying to distance themselves from the video game moniker](https://books.google.com/books?id=yn3nDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT14&ots=AdelPLaKen&pg=PT14#v=onepage&q&f=false) and the [Atari 2600 Computer Video System](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131956/a_history_of_gaming_platforms_.php?print=1) due to the [infamous video game crash of 1983,](http://thegaminghistorian.com/the-gaming-historian-the-video-game-crash-of-1983/) because if they did not, stores would not buy such a worthless product. [One of the things they did is design the Nintendo Entertainment System to load from the side to make a mental association with a how V.H.S. tapes are loaded into a V.C.R.](http://nintendoeverything.com/nes-designer-explains-the-front-loading-slot-why-the-zapper-was-bundled-in/) However the spring loaded mechanism used caused the N.E.S. to stop reading the cartridges after enough games have been inserted.

Thus with history as the way it went, video games and computer games have been rendered mostly distinct. Sure, [Sony Computer Entertainment of America](https://www.sony.com/en_us/SCA/company-news/press-releases/sony-computer-entertainment-america-inc/2016/sony-computer-entertainment-and-sony-network-enter.html) makes its bread and butter off of Playstations, but the playstations are popularly marketed as video game consoles everywhere they are sold, and in every publication that discusses them.

Comment: Thank you for the links! Especially the Nintendo gadgets